# ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration is not respecting the bean in the Application for ErrorWebExceptionHandler type

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I have created a component of ErrorWebExceptionHandler type by extending AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler class as below .

```
@Component
public class ExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {---}
```

I assume this should suppress the bean creation using the below method in ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration class and my component should be respected as the method has a ConditionalOnMissingBean annotation for the type.(
[Github Link](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/reactive/error/ErrorWebFluxAutoConfiguration.java) )

```
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(
        value = {ErrorWebExceptionHandler.class},
        search = SearchStrategy.CURRENT
    )
    @Order(-1)
    public ErrorWebExceptionHandler errorWebExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, ResourceProperties resourceProperties, ObjectProvider<ViewResolver> viewResolvers, ServerCodecConfigurer serverCodecConfigurer, ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler exceptionHandler = new DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler(errorAttributes, resourceProperties, this.serverProperties.getError(), applicationContext);
        exceptionHandler.setViewResolvers((List)viewResolvers.orderedStream().collect(Collectors.toList()));
        exceptionHandler.setMessageWriters(serverCodecConfigurer.getWriters());
        exceptionHandler.setMessageReaders(serverCodecConfigurer.getReaders());
        return exceptionHandler;
    }
```

If I specifically give my component an order less than -1, my component is taking precedence(as shown below). But, I feel like that is an unwanted extra burden and could/should be avoided.

```
@Component
@Order(-2)
public class ExceptionHandler extends AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler {---}
```

Comment: `@Order` should not be necessary. I suspect your handler is not being defined until after the auto-configured handler so it does not cause the auto-configured handler to back off. I’d need to see an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to identify why that is the case.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have created a small [gihub repo](https://github.com/ajmalch/sring-webflux-exception-handling) with a working example for you. One thing I noticed that is if I don' have  `@ResponseStatus` on ResourceNotFoundException, the behavior is as expected. But, I need that to give correct Http Status based on exception.
Also as I mentioned earlier if I uncomment `@Order`, it is working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mistaken when I said that `@Order` should not be necessary. It's unnecessary from Spring Boot's perspective (where its sole `ErrorWebExceptionHandler` is replaced with your custom implementation), but is still necessary from a Spring WebFlux perspective.

Spring WebFlux supports multiple `WebExceptionHander` instances and calls them in order. Spring Boot orders its `DefaultErrorWebExceptionHandler` at `-1` which ensures that it runs before Spring WebFlux's `ResponseStatusExceptionHandler` which `WebFluxConfigurationSupport` orders at `0`.

To ensure that your custom `ErrorWebExceptionHandler` runs before WebFlux's `ResponseStatusExceptionHandler` it must be ordered with higher precedence (a lower value) than `ResponseStatusExceptionHandler`. The latter is ordered at `0` so you should use an order of `-1` or less.

Comment: Thanks for your response @AndyWilkinson. So, it is mandatory to have an `@order` annotation. Do you then think  `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` annotation has no effect and could/should be removed from errorWebExceptionHandler method above as our scope here is WebFlux only?

Comment: I don’t think it should be removed as it does have an effect. The auto-configured `ErrorWebExceptionHandler` will back off when you define your own.

Comment: Ah, I got what you are saying. ErrorWebExceptionHandler will back off, however WebFlux ResponseStatusExceptionHandler will not. If it is designed like that, I am moving on with `@Order` in my custom `ErrorWebExceptionHandler`. Thanks for your time and help. Appreciate it very much.